# How can I prevent Phonegap from closing app when there is an error?

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application built using PhoneGap (Android) that is essentially a shell for a web app, that would (in the future) allow for push notifications and offline reading of downloaded pages from the web app.

My problem is this - if the connection to the network is lost or turned off in the middle of use, and a link is clicked on a page, there is an error: `Application Error: Could not find url: '...'`, and the app closes. I want to be able to prevent the app from closing, and if possible, change this error message.

I know that the standard *would be* to use the PhoneGap API to check the network connection, then handle it myself, but because this is a shell for a web App, the only place I can do this is on app startup. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by checking out the source code for the [childbrowserplugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser).

The code there for onlocationchange is allowing for intercepting all webrequests in and out of a webview.  It sounds like your app has needs similar to this.

Comment: Using childbrowser plugin was not necessarily the most direct way to solve the problem, but definitely works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to add the permissions for wifi,Gps,Internet into the Android Manifest file. While you have to add the code for checking the Internet Connection available condition into you code as well..

If both the connection doesnot fullfills then try to add the toast message that Internet connection is not available..

I think your problem will definitely be solved...

Comment: I explained that this would work if this was a code executing on the device, but the phonegap application is a shell for a web application so this doesn't work.